# How to change the font of column name

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, column

Is there a way for me to change the font size/ family for a particular column name for Default New Form web part. (jquery/ SPD) Like the following image (diff from default style) Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a CSS file to the page/master page (You can use a script editor or content editor, your choice really).

For editing column names you are looking at this:

```
<style>
 .ms-vh2-nofilter, .ms-vh2-nofilter-notextalign, .ms-vh2-nofilter-perm, .ms-vh a, .ms-vh2, .ms-vh2 a
{
 font-family:"Times New Roman";
 font-size: 50px;
}
</style>
```

Edit (Misread the question my bad)
To change the font of **all** field names on a form add this css

```
<style>
.ms-standardheader
{
  font-family:"Times New Roman";
 font-size: 50px;
}
</style>
```

You will want to edit the default web parts of the form (easiest if you set the form you want as the default via SPD) in SP click list/library > Forms Web Parts> Default New Form.  Then add a script web part and copy paste the above into it.

Comment: sorry im still new in sharepoint. do you have a sample code for the css? for instance the column name is "HR Administrator" thanks a lot.

Comment: @SerenaKoh I have updated the answer. If you want to do this to only certain individual field names then you will have to use SPD and add your own class name/ or directly apply css via inline. Here is a good website to learn css: http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp